# Can I skip Mass Effect 1 and go to Mass Effect 2

Tags: mass-effect

I have mass effect 1 on the Xbox 360, recently got myself a high end gaming PC and have been looking at the three game collection.

Have been told that the second one is much better than the first, question is:

Can i skip playing number 1 and just go straight to 2? Is there a major plot line etc that carries over and I will be sitting there scratching my head? Generally speaking I like to play a game from the start, but after six attempts on the Xbox I hate it. Is it different on the PC?

I know 2 - 3 the save games can carry over?

Comment: not a duplicate at all, its a complete different question?

Comment: I did this exact same thing: I played ME2 then ME3, still have never played ME1. I found there were some plot items here and there I didn't understand, but overall I still enjoyed ME2's plot without playing ME1.

Comment: It's partially duplicate; both ask if there's something in ME1 needed to understand ME2, but you also ask if the PC version is different from the Xbox one.

Comment: To help your decision, you can buy the Genesis DLC for Mass Effect 2 on PC, which summarizes Mass Effect 1 and allows you to make the choice for the major decisions in ME1.

Answer (score 3):

You can skip ME 1 if you so choose. However consider these points before making your decision:

1. ME 1 has a quite bit of story you would be missing out on if you skip it.
2. There is one crucial decision regarding which squad member you want to sacrifice and which one you want to save.
3. You have the option to save Major Kirrahe, who is worth some points towards military strength in ME 3.
4. You have a confrontation with Urdnot Wrex. If you can diffuse it, Wrex will be in ME 2 uniting the clans and in ME 3 as leader of the Krogan clans. Without him, Urdnot Wreave will be in charge in ME 3 and you will not be able to save Eve from dying.
5. There is an encounter with the last Rachni queen. You could choose to let go and disappear, but she comes back in ME 3.
6. Any paragon/renegade decisions you take in ME 1 will get carried over.
7. Some amount of resources you find in ME 1 are carried over, helpful for researching upgrades in ME 2.
8. Romances are carried over from ME 1.
9. Experience the frustration in driving the Mako. It climbs and climbs as they say.

These are but some points to consider. I might have missed some. But all in all you can skip ME 1 if you choose. But IMO ME 1 is a very enjoyable game, I feel you should experience it. But if you want a prior saved file for ME 1 without making all these decisions, paragon/renegade choices etc, you can try [Mass Effect Saves](http://www.masseffectsaves.com/)

Comment: I have experienced it on the Xbox but might try on the pc, I hate it, go about half way through game, died forgot to save and lost it all. My own fault but it was a struggle to get to that point so could not be arsed to do it again. I might get the collection and try. What happens if you do not have a ME1 save when you start 2?

Comment: You're missing the biggest one: Wrex.

Comment: If you start without a save there are just some default assumptions to be made (e.g. who survived etc.). It's possible to do so, but you'd be better off either replaying the game on Xbox or pick a savegame that's as close to your former progress as possible (if you still remember it).

Comment: Is there a way to hide these numbers points in a *SPOILER WARNING* section? I feel like an accidental glance into this question/answer may upset some viewers...

Comment: So what? I only played it for the first time less than a year ago. And obviously people looking for the answer to this question haven't played it either...

Comment: You could also use the mass effect genesis comic that takes you through the major decisions of ME1 and have them carry over